# How can I make the behind view of jeremy feinstein's SlidingMenu clickable

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

I am using jeremy feinstein's SlidingMenu for an Android app. When the left menu is opened, I still have a remaining space from the behind view uncovered. In that remaining view I have a button that I want to handle onClick. But when I click on it or in any other part of the view, it just closes the left menu.

How can I make this work? I tried to set `sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN|SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);` but it didn't work this way. This is the code for my SlidingMenu object:

```
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN|SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    // set the left menu
    sm.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_left);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame_left, new LeftMenuListFragment())
            .commit();

    // set the right menu
    sm.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_right);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame_right, new RightMenuListFragment())
            .commit();
```

I will also attach an image drawn by me to explain better what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code of jeremy feinstein's SlidingMenu, I found number value on the constant value for use with setTouchModeAbove() :

```
/** Constant value for use with setTouchModeAbove(). Allows the SlidingMenu to be opened with a swipe
 * gesture on the screen's margin
 */
public static final int TOUCHMODE_MARGIN = 0;

/** Constant value for use with setTouchModeAbove(). Allows the SlidingMenu to be opened with a swipe
 * gesture anywhere on the screen
 */
public static final int TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN = 1;
```

while you set `sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN|SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);` ,in fact the vaule of touchModeAbobe is `1|0` that equal 1 .

I suggest you try `sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);`,it may work.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try this fix and I'll tell you if it worked.